# Angular: Eager loading makes component to not be rendered

Tags: angular

I want to have the following structure in DOM:

```
<myapp-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <myapp-user-management>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <myapp-users></myapp-users>
  </myapp-user-management>

</myapp-root>
```

**(1)** I made a lazy loading for `UserManagementModule` in **root-routing.module.ts** like so

```
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    ...
    children: [
      ...
      {
        path: 'userManagement', 
        loadChildren: '../user-management/user-management.module#UserManagementModule'
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(rootRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RootRoutingModule {
}
```

and then I imported the routing module in RootModule

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    RootRoutingModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class RootModule {
}
```

The `root.component.html` has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**(2)** After that I wanted to make an **eager** load of `UsersModule`. So I in **user-management-routing.module.ts** I have

```
const userManagementRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserManagementComponent
  }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(userManagementRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserManagementRoutingModule { }
```

and in **user-management.module.ts** I have

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    UserManagementRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class UserManagementModule { }
```

The `user-management.component.html` has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**(3)** Then I written the **users-routing.module.ts** as follows

```
const usersRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(usersRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule {
}
```

and the **users.module.ts** as follows

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UsersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UsersRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

**The problem is** it renders

```
<myapp-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <myapp-users></myapp-users>
</myapp-root>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The users route must be a child route of the unique, empty-path route in userManagementRoutes.

Comment: Besides @JBNizet comment, you can still import `UsersModule` within `UserManagementModule` to bundle them together but as he stated, `users` route should be defined within `userManagementRoutes` as if you are defining a lazy loaded module.

Comment: @JBNizet and @Bunyamin Coskuner Yeah, but this is not a modular approach. I want to have all the user routes in the `user-routing.module.ts`. Suppose, in the future, I will add another module, say `user-groups` module. Then I don't want to crowd the countries routes in user-management routes. I want them to be separate

Comment: Not everything needs to be an Angular module. You can simple export a const defining the users routes, and use `children: USERS_ROUTES`.

Comment: @JBNizet I know, but maybe tomorrow the client will tell me to move the Users section in another place. Then I want to make this thing quick. This is the reason for which I want to make a Users Module

Comment: Then you'll move that constant to another route. An Angular module won't make anything easier. Your scenario is highly unlikely anyway: the users routes won't suddenly move from the users management module to the flowers-management module: users are not flowers. And you'll have much bigger problems to solve if that happens, like changing all the URLs.

Comment: If you need to move the module somewhere else, you need to update `import` statement anyway because you import `UsersModule`. You might as well use this import statement => `import { UsersModule, USERS_ROUTE } from './users/users.module';`